# Galeria simples em CSS

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando fazer uma galeria pra um site e gostaria que as fotos fossem exibidas apenas dentro da `div class="conteudo"`.
Tentei definir um `height` e um `width` para a `div` mas as fotos aparecem como na imagem abaixo, empilhadas e sendo exibida fora da `div`. Elas deveriam ficar centralizadas acima da 'div id="thumb"'

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**HTML**

```
<div class="conteudo" style="height:680px;">
  <div id="galeria">
    <img id="foto1" src="imgs/002.jpg" alt="">
    <img id="foto2" src="imgs/003.jpg" alt="">
    <img id="foto3" src="imgs/04.jpg" alt="">
    <img id="foto4" src="imgs/05.jpg" alt="">
    <img id="foto5" src="imgs/06.jpg" alt="">
    <img id="foto6" src="imgs/07.jpg" alt="">
    <img id="foto7" src="imgs/08.jpg" alt="">
    <img id="foto8" src="imgs/09.jpg" alt="">
    <img id="foto9" src="imgs/10.png" alt="">
    <img id="foto10" src="imgs/11.png" alt="">
    <img id="foto11" src="imgs/12.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div id="thumb" class="thumb" style=" display:grid; max-height: 80%;">
    <a href="#foto1"><img src="imgs/002.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#foto2"><img src="imgs/003.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#foto3"><img src="imgs/04.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#foto4"><img src="imgs/05.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#foto5"><img src="imgs/06.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#foto6"><img src="imgs/07.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#foto7"><img src="imgs/08.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#foto8"><img src="imgs/09.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#foto9"><img src="imgs/10.png" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#foto10"><img src="imgs/11.png" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#foto11"><img src="imgs/12.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.conteudo {
  background-color: rgba(255, 250, 250, 0.3);
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.thumb {
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.thumb img {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

#galeria {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: 675px;
  width: 900px;
}

#galeria img {
  max-height: 675px;
  min-height: 675px;
  min-width: 900px;
  max-width: 900px;
}
```

Comment: Tem como descrever melhor o problema? Como que deveriam estar as imagens? Como estão? Entre em [edit] e melhore sua pergunta, apenas com a imagem não tem como identificar o problema.

Comment: da uma olhada https://lennonsantos.github.io/ideias/simple-slider/

Comment: @LennonS.Bueno Muito obrigado, adicionei esse slide e ficou muito melhor do que minha ideia anterior

Comment: @PabloNicolas que bom que pude ajudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basta dizer a tag img que ela precisa ocupar 100% do espaço da div em que ela se encontra.

```
img{
  width: 100%;
 }
```